# After updating to Xcode 8 beta 6, lost CKErrorCode and .rawValue from associated enums

Tags: swift, xcode, error-handling, enums, ckerror

I had a switch statement in Xcode 7.3 that (after passing `error: NSError` as an argument) worked like so:

```
if let code:CKErrorCode = CKErrorCode(rawValue: error.code) {
    switch code {
    case .NotAuthenticated: etc...
    }
}
```

After migrating to Swift 3.0 in Xcode 8 beta 6, I started getting errors saying that CKErrorCode is not recognized. I'm still importing cloud, and the migration lowercased my enums and I've tried to change it like so:

```
switch error.code {
case .notAuthenticated.rawValue: etc...
}
```

but that also seems to error (the beta seems to be buggy on my system so the errors keep disappearing and reappearing, so it's hard to tell as I code now and it may just be my system, but they persist when I compile). I've been scanning https://swift.org/migration-guide/#known-migration-issues and https://swift.org/migration-guide/ but haven't found anything yet and when I google CKErrorCode the documentation (which I'm assuming is ignoring Swift 3 since it's in beta) seems to say my previous syntax is kosher.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this? Did enums lose `.rawValue`? Enums seemed to have changed, but I'm having difficulty finding documentation on what I should be doing. Is there an alternative to CKErrorCode that will recognize these enum cases? Please don't tell me cloud kit error handling changed more dramatically than that :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just need to cast from Swift 3 Error to NSError

Comment: My error is passed in as NSError and when I option click `error` it's described as `let error: NSError`...did you mean I need to cast from NSError to Swift 3 Error (I'm kinda confused how the bridging works to be honest). (error as! NSError).code warns that I'm casting from NSError to NSError

Comment: Also is CKErrorCode gone, or do I need to fix something about my configuration?

Comment: casting to CKError code worked. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion to CKError from NSError as shown below:

```
let nsError: NSError = NSError() // NSError variable. 

let cError = CKError(_nsError: nsError)

let cErrorCode = cError.code
```

Comment: You might want to add some commentary to explain this code-only answer.